Turning Deutsch-Josza into a continuous problem
I am wondering whether anyone has investigated if there is a notion of a continuous oracle. My starting off point is to consider the Deutsch-Josza problem, in which the oracle acts on the state in a different way depending on whether the underlying function is either constant or balanced. What I would like to consider is a case where instead of making discrete queries to the oracle, we can instead apply an unknown evolution operator $e^{-iH_ct}$ or $e^{-iH_bt}$ for some desired time $t$, and then apply other operations and do measurements. Then define the continuous query complexity as the minimum time $t$ needed to evolve the state under the unknown oracle evolution operator. Does a notion like this already exist in the literature? If not, is it because there is some obvious reason it is uninteresting? A cursory Google search pulled up nothing that seemed relevant.
I imagine this may simply reduce the usual Deutsch-Josza problem where the oracle is either some unitary $U_c = E^{-iH_c}$ or $U_b = e^{-iH_b}$ (i.e. $t = 1$ or some other fixed $t$ could work here), and so nothing really significantly different is happening here except that now we are allowing ourselves to apply arbitrary powers of the oracle. But I don't know what difference this may make.
I also think that this may end up being essentially the same as Hamiltonian simulation.

If it’s constant could it be periodic with period 2?

That is, wouldn’t $U_c^2=U_c^4=\cdots=I$?

yeah something like this would need to happen, so the algorithm would end up having an optimal time to measure. This is sorta similar to a continuous quantum walk on a graph, where you can find the state at a certain vertex with a periodic amplitude. In fact, it was looking into quantum walks that I first started thinking about this
